# APIs failing due to Chrome and Chromedriver compatibility problem on Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

My Spring Boot app is deployed on Heroku and I am using Chrome and Chromedriver buildpacks.

Everytime Chrome's stable version is updated and I deploy an app update on Heroku, the APIs that depend on these buildpacks return "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version  119", because Chrome version 120 is the current stable version and Chromedriver hasn't caught up yet.

How do I solve this once and for all? Should I include Chrome binary in my app on GitHub and point Selenium to its bin so I will be able to control the version of Chrome? Is there a way to do that?

Or is there some way to make Heroku work with the version of Chrome I want using an environment variable?

When I add GOOGLE-CHROME-CHANNEL:stable, it installs the current stable version which might not be available for Chromedriver for some days. Is there a way to choose the previous compatible stable version instead of the current one?

To my config vars, I have tweaked GOOGLE-CHROME-VERSION, GOOGLE-CHROME-CHANNEL, CHROMEDRIVE-VERSION in previous times to get the APIs to work. This works for some days but when I deploy a new update on the app, I most times get that error again. In all, this makes the app very unstable especially because these APIs are the core APIs of the application.

Comment: "Should I include Chrome binary in my app on GitHub and point Selenium to its bin so I will be able to control the version of Chrome?"—absolutely not. Just pin your Chrome version to whatever the latest Chromedriver is (the driver should be pinned, too).

Comment: [This forked Chrome buildpack](https://github.com/awl19/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome#configuring-the-downloaded-version-of-chrome-browser) looks like it supports (and requires) an explicit version to be set.

Comment: Hello @Chris, thank you as I was able to install the desired version. Selenium has been throwing a timeout error since I added that build pack. I didn't change the code.

_Failed to shutdown Driver Command Executor. org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to stop. Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-1049-aws', java.version: '17.0.4' Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 119.0.6045.159, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 119.0.6045.105_

Comment: I tried to adjust the versions because they obviously are different by specifying
**CHROME_VERSION = {version}
 CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION = {version}**

When I deployed the changes, it installed the versions and other versions from the previous configuration. 
I have made other changes in order to solve the compounding problems and now 3 different versions of Chrome is installed per deployment and I can't seem to locate them in my dyno when I run 'heroku bash'

Comment: Managed to solve the version problem.  I am now getting this error message

_org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [f36262cfd20cd7e2c6ba6591cb7b8906, get {url=https://www.ebay.com/b/Home-Audio-Radio-Tuners/22635/bn_739485}]

Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome-headless-shell, browserVersion: 120.0.6099.35, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 120.0.6099.35 (f6c1e93f00ea  ... , goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:33597} se:cdpVersion: 120.0.6099.35,_